# How Reuse My Qt Quick Controls in Multiple project like c++ library?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquickcontrols2, qtquickcontrols

I have read article [Adding Libraries to Projects](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html) for Reusing my c++ classes in my diffrent qt quick applications,

I have many [Custom qml types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html) Like `MyCustomGridView.qml` and I using this in many project But I have to copy the file in my new Project and When I extend this in one project I have to make change by hand in all proejcts.

My question is How can I reuse this qml types like c++ library in diffrent projects?

Comment: take a look at  qml plugins: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html

Comment: if you are using a subdir project to link the same qml project in different libraries, why do you have to copy them? just add it as subproject no? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Moia Can You tell me how?I think this not possible.